# Sandbox Solution: Why won't it update when published?

Tags: visual-studio, sandbox-solution, solution-package

I have a weird problem in VS 2013 working with a SharePoint NCSS Sandbox Solution. Whenever I right-click and Publish the .wsp locally on the file system, it publishes an old version of the .wsp. By this I mean the content updates and new files I've added to the solution do not land in the generated .wsp. The .wsp even has an old file date on it, from the first time it was deployed for the day, or whenever it happened to work last.

Sometimes it takes a restart of VS to get it to kick. Occasionally, a full reboot of my VM is required.

Has anyone ever run into this, and if so, how did you fix it?

I feel like I'm going crazy with this. It's like VS just picks up the first .wsp that was compiled and stuffs it in the Publish location. Which is laudable, if saving CPU cycles is a priority. But it kind of messes with the whole "make a new .wsp from my updated content" thing.

Comment: No, this is not how it works in my experience.  make doubly sure you are publishing to the location you think you are. Delete the already present wsp on the file system and re-publish. If the new wsp doesn't show up, you are publishing to a different location.

Comment: Also, make sure your new content is actually included in the package. Open up the "package" node in Solution Explorer and check that your stuff is in there.

Comment: I'll double and triple check, but I'm fairly certain I'm publishing to the correct location, and if the .wsp already exists, telling it to overwrite.